# Sql to linq (How to wrtie Sql Query in Linq)

Tags: sql, linq

This is my query. it is working fine in SQL and return the result that i want.
how can i write in Linq.

```
select * from g2issuetype it,storingsitems si 
where 1 not in 
(select 1 from contractstoringsitems cs where scontractid=110
and cs.issuetypeid=it.issuetypeid and cs.storingsitemid=si.storingsitemid) order by issuetype,storingsitem
```

i am trying this but its not correct. i am new in Linq any one can help me to write this query in Linq

```
(from it in _context.G2issueType
         from si in _context.StoringsItems
         where si.StoringsItemId != (from cs in _context.ContractStoringsitems
                                     where cs.Scontractid == id
                                     && cs.Issuetypeid == it.IssueTypeId
                                     && cs.Storingsitemid == si.StoringsItemId )
         select new StoringsitemsViewMode { })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Any`(it is like `exists/not exists` in `sql`) operator like this

```
from it in g2issuetype
            join si in storingsitems
            where !contractstoringsitems.Any(x => scontractid == 110 && x.issuetypeid = it.issuetypeid && x.storingsitemid = si.storingsitemid)
            select new StoringsitemsViewMode { }
```